# Setter injection in Spring

Tags: spring

I am Running Spring Core program and I got this Error. and I configure build path and add all jar files.
structure of project
[image: enter image descri!ption here]

WishMessageGenerator.java

```
package com.nt.beans;
import java.util.Date;

public class WishMessageGenerator {
    private Date date;
    public WishMessageGenerator() {
        System.out.println("WishMessageGenerator:0-param      constructor");
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        System.out.println("WishMessageGenerator:setDate(-)");
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String generateMessage(String user) {
        int hour = 0;
        System.out.println("Injected date::"+date);
        hour = date.getHours();
        if(hour < 12)
            return "Good Morning :::"+user;
        else if(hour < 16)
            return "Good AfterNoon :::"+user;
        else if(hour < 20)
            return "Good Evening :::"+user;
        else
            return "Good Night"+user;
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!-- Dependent Bean class cfg -->
    <bean id="dt" class="java.util.Date" />

    <!-- Target Bean class cfg -->
    <bean id="wmg" class="com.nt.beans.WishMessageGenerator">
        <property name="date" ref="dt"></property><!-- Setter injection -->
    </bean>
</beans>
```

SetterInection.java

```
package com.nt.test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import com.nt.beans.WishMessageGenerator;

public class SetterInjection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resource res = null;
        BeanFactory factory = null;
        Object obj = null;
        WishMessageGenerator generator = null;
        res = new   FileSystemResource("src/com/nt/cfgs/applicationContext.xml");
        factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
        obj = factory.getBean("wmg");
        generator = (WishMessageGenerator)obj;
           System.out.println("result:::"+generator.generateMessage("KingRk"));
    }
}
```

I got this output:
    Error: Unable to initialize main class com.nt.test.SetterInjection
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
The output is:
[image]

Comment: You are missing dependencies. I strongly suggest to use Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies instead of you scanning the internet downloading jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to add jar into class path not module path

Add jar into class path using Build path

[Buid path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns9T5.png)

Comment: But why? I thought modules was suppose to make Java better, safer, encapsulated and more manageable, as stated in [Project Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/)